# won't load after adding php script

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, codeigniter

This is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#sepatu").click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var site_url = "<?php echo base_url()?>index.php/pelanggan/dyos_sepatu/";
            $("#content").load(site_url);
        })
    })
</script>
```

This is what I want to load :

```
<select name="jenis" class="form-control">
        <?php
            foreach ($jenis->result() as $data){?>
            <option value="<?php echo $data->id_jenis_sepatu?>"><?php echo $data->nama_jenis?></option>
        <?php
            }
        ?>
    </select>
```

My problem appears after I'm adding the php script :

```
<?php
        foreach ($jenis->result() as $data){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data->id_jenis_sepatu?>"><?php echo $data->nama_jenis?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

It won't load. When I delete that script, it loads. 
Here is my controller :

```
public function dyos_sepatu(){
        $data['jenis'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM jenis_sepatu");
        $this->load->view('pelanggan/sepatu_dyos',true,$data);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Send data to view as below

```
public function dyos_sepatu(){
        $data['jenis'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM jenis_sepatu")->result();
        $this->load->view('pelanggan/sepatu_dyos',true,$data);
    }
```

Then in view `$jenis->result()` as just `$jenis`. Try once

Like this...

```
<?php
        foreach ($jenis as $data){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $data->id_jenis_sepatu;?>"><?php echo $data->nama_jenis;?></option>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
public function dyos_sepatu(){
    $data['jenis'] = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM jenis_sepatu");
    echo $this->load->view('pelanggan/sepatu_dyos',true,$data); // note the echo here
}
```

Need to echoing content to page for `jQuery .load()` render the page.

Comment: it cause ` Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string`

Answer (score -1):

I think you forgot to terminate  php in this `<?php echo $data->id_jenis_sepatu; ?>` Also check between option tag